# Application of De Morgan's Law in Sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This topic is new to me and would like some tips to how to to solve the following:

> Suppose set $C$ is a complement of $A\cup B$. Please give an alternative (but equivalent) definition of $C$ using De Morgan's Laws.

Comment: What *are* De Morgan's laws?

Comment: "*I would like some tips to how to solve...*" The first and most important tip I can give you is to learn the rigorous definitions to terminology used.  Knowing the proper definitions is often the only truly difficult step in problems like these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$C=A^c \cap B^c $$ In English,  the complement of the union is the intersection of the complements...

Answer (score -1):

$x \in C$ iff $x \notin (A \cup B)$ iff $x \notin A \land x \notin B$.

this follows from the logical variant of de Morgan:

$x \in C$ iff $\lnot(x \in (A\cup B))$ iff $\lnot(x \in A \lor x \in B)$ iff
$\lnot (x \in A) \lor \lnot (x \in B)$, and $\lnot( x \in B)$ holds exactly when $x \in B^c$ etc.